Cannot Access Azure DevOps Variable for resourceName in Environment at Runtime
I am setting up a deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps that targets a specific virtual machine (VM) resource in an environment. I want to dynamically pass the VM resource name using a variable defined in the Azure DevOps Variables section (the UI at the top right of the pipeline editor). However, I am unable to access this variable at runtime when using it in the resourceName field of the environment.
My Pipeline YAML
Here is the relevant section of my pipeline:
jobs:
- deployment: DeployToVM
  displayName: 'Deploy to VM'
  environment: 
    name: 'Production' # Static environment name
    resourceName: ${{ ResourceName }} # Variable for the VM resource name
    resourceType: VirtualMachine

  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo "Deploying to $(ResourceName)"
          displayName: "Deployment Script"

What I Did

I added a pipeline variable in the Variables section of the Azure DevOps UI (top right):

Name: ResourceName
Value: MyResource (the name of the VM resource in the Production environment).


Referenced this variable in the YAML using resourceName: ${{ ResourceName }}.

The Problem
When I run the pipeline, I get the following error:
Resource '' does not exist in environment 'Production'.

It seems like the resourceName field cannot resolve the value of the variable ResourceName. However, I can successfully echo the value of $(ResourceName) in the steps section, so the variable itself is accessible in other contexts.
What I Tried

Tried using both $(ResourceName) and ${{ ResourceName }} in the resourceName field.
Verified that the Production environment exists and contains the VM resource MyResource.
Tested with hardcoding the value (resourceName: 'MyResource'), which works fine.


My Questions

Why can’t I use a variable for the resourceName field in the environment definition?
Is there a way to dynamically reference a VM resource in an environment using a variable defined in the Azure DevOps Variables section?

Additional Information

I am using Azure DevOps YAML pipelines with a multi-stage setup.
The VM (MyResource) is correctly registered in the Production environment.

Any help or insights would be appreciated!

Using pipeline variables
You're using the wrong syntax to reference variables.
Instead of:
${{ ResourceName }}

Use template expressions (compile time):
${{ variables.ResourceName }}

Or use macro syntax (runtime):
$(ResourceName)

Using pipeline parameters
If you need user input when queuing a new pipeline I'd recommend using a pipeline parameter instead of a variable.
Parameters are a better choice because they are strongly-typed, will be compiled and are immediately visible when you queue a new build. The only good reason IMO to use UI variables is if you need to set secret variables.
As an alternative to variables, use a pipeline parameter:
# my-pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  - name: ResourceName
    type: String
    displayName: Name of the virtual machine

jobs:
- deployment: DeployToVM
  displayName: 'Deploy to VM'
  environment: 
    name: 'Production' # Static environment name
    resourceName: ${{ parameters.ResourceName }} # <------ use pipeline parameter
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  # ...


getting this error when using parameter A value for the 'ResourceName' parameter must be provided. how to pass value to parameter please refer screenshot ?  As I am defining variable using Azure Devops UI  @Rui

@Ranjan if you use parameters you don't need to define a variable in the UI. See my example. If you're using templates you need to add the parameter at both the pipeline and your template as well.
See Use parameters in pipelines
and Template parameters

Thanks , it worked , I want to know How we access variable in resourceName  that is defined in UI  @Rui

@Ranjan I'm not completely sure if you can use variables set in the UI in environments. Anyway, take a look into the first part of my answer (added more details).
But I'd strongly recommend using a pipeline parameter. when using YAML pipelines parameters are a better choice because they are strongly-typed, will be compiled and are immediately visible when you queue a new build. The only good reason IMO to use UI variables is if you need to set secrets variables.

@Ranjan added more details.

As far as I have tested, we can only use template expressions (processed at compile time) ${{ variables.ResourceName }}to define the resourceName:  property of the environment referenced by a deployment job.
variables:
- name: ResourceName
  value: E-Windows11-10

jobs:
- deployment: DeployToVM
  displayName: 'Deploy to VM'
  environment: 
    name: 'Production' # Static environment name
    resourceName: ${{ variables.ResourceName }} # Variable for the VM resource name
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo "Deploying to $(ResourceName)"
          displayName: "Deployment Script"

However, it makes us unable to dynamically override variable value in the web UI before queueing the build.
For this, you may consider using parameters instead. It also supports input of new values other than default, when you manually run the pipeline.
parameters:
- name: ResourceName
  default: E-Windows11-10

jobs:
- deployment: DeployToVM
  displayName: 'Deploy to VM'
  environment: 
    name: 'Production' # Static environment name
    resourceName: ${{ parameters.ResourceName }} # Parameter for the VM resource name
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo "Deploying to ${{ parameters.ResourceName }}"
          displayName: "Deployment Script"



Besides, you may also define multiple values as a picklist for the parameters to select.
parameters:
- name: ResourceName
  default: E-Windows11-10
  values:
  - E-Windows11-10
  - E-Windows2022-10
  - E-Linux2204-10

jobs:
- deployment: DeployToVM
  displayName: 'Deploy to VM'
  environment: 
    name: 'Production' # Static environment name
    resourceName: ${{ parameters.ResourceName }} # Parameter for the VM resource name
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo "Deploying to ${{ parameters.ResourceName }}"
          displayName: "Deployment Script"




You can use Template expression syntax to define the resourceName: and if you want to deploy to multiple environments using the same pipeline, you can configure it like this.
parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: 'Environment:'
    type: string
    default: Dev
    values:
      - Dev
      - QA

variables:
- name: Dev-resourceName
  value: VM1
- name: QA-resourceName
  value: VM2

jobs:
- deployment: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  environment: 
    name: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    resourceName: ${{ variables[format('{0}-resourceName', parameters.environment)] }}
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  # ...

